# iPhone .ipa file goes blank after opening splash screen?

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created Map application and it is running on my mac machine with xcode. But when I created its ipa file and sync with my iPhone device it does not open. Only splash screen 
get open and getting close. I have my developer and distribution certificate sign with device UDID. My client also could not able to run the application remotely....thanks in advance for your help. plz suggest what I am missing here??

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

  //sleep(0.5);



arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];             //pickerview radius array

[arrayNo addObject:@"5km"];
[arrayNo addObject:@"10km"];
[arrayNo addObject:@"15km"];

   [window addSubview:[viewController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

**Upadated: with leaks problems**

I am also checking the possibility with memory leaks and using instrument tool I am getting 100% leaks at the time of launching the application. Its NSPlaceholderString leaks on following code...

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;


    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"..myurl......lat=%f&lng=%f&radius=5",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

    radiusinurl.text = @"5km";
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    //Initialize the delegate.
    **XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];**   //5.3% leaks
    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    //Start parsing the XML file.
    **BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];**           //0.2% leaks

        [xmlParser release];
        [parser release];
  if(success)

    {                     
 NSLog(@"show me [appDelegate.markers count] %d",[appDelegate.markers count]);


        annobjs = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
        if([appDelegate.markers count] == 0)
        { //99% leaks on below line where I am calling another method
**[self performSelector:@selector(showingThreeResultsOnCurrentLocation)   withObject:nil];**         //99% leaks
        }
        else
        {//some logic

        }

    }
    else
    {

         //logic
    }}}}
```

I have commented leaks at the end of line. Can you correct my code. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I get the same problem. check it with your deployment target and also run in your device with latest ios

Comment: One month ago my client and I was able to test the beta version of my application. what has happen now?? Any policy change by apple?? I am having xcode 3.2 & iPhone sdk 4.2.3. Using iPhone 4 device (4.3.2) for testing

Comment: need to show code of splash screen view and dismiss and after added the main controller

Comment: I have just put Default.png image for splash screen which remain till ViewDidLoad process the code. I have not gave any code for splash.

Comment: ok no prob but post didFinishLaunching method code

Comment: where is viewController define?

Comment: not define.....I have define when I applied navigation controller. But later I have removed that code

Comment: why? you have to initialize the view controller and then add into your window. check my below answer. if you get the problem then let me know

Comment: Can you check my updated code problem because my ipa file is still crashing sometimes. Please suggest me correct way..

Comment: no improvement by NSAutoReleasePool in -void showingThreeResultsOnCurrentLocation {} method...

Comment: exactly  NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL]; and [self performSelector:@selector(showingThreeResultsOnCurrentLocation)   withObject:nil]; lines having leaks after trying autorelease also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize view controller first

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  //This is for autoresize when in phone call mode(which does not work yet)
     [dict setObject:@"trigger" forKey:@"frame"];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"trigger"
                                                object:self
                                              userInfo:dict];

     arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];             //pickerview radius array

     [arrayNo addObject:@"5km"];
     [arrayNo addObject:@"10km"];
     [arrayNo addObject:@"15km"];

    viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigaitonController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nav];

  self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
  self.window.rootViewController = nav;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```